# Use array variable to load javascripts at bottom of the page

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to use a kind of global array to define what javascripts should be loaded at the end of the page. This way, I can dynamically add javascript files.

The problem is that the base template is being rendered first. Imagine this base html:

```
{% set javascriptList = [ 'js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js', 'js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js', 'js/main.js' ] %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>my project</title>
</head>
<body>

{% block container %}
content goes here
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {% for js in javascriptList %}
        <script src="{{ asset(js) }}"></script>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Then I would have a page, something like this:

```
{% extends base.html.twig %}

{% block container %}
<h1>Demo</h1>

Bla bla

Code I want to reuse:

{% include 'code-with-js.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Then my code-with-js.html.twig would be:

```
<div id="DemoContent">
Some content, with a <a href="#" rel="tooltip">tooltip</a> thingy maybe.
</div>

{% set javascriptList = javascriptList|merge(['js/tooltip.js']) %}
```

So, using this setup, I can make sure that the correct javascript is being added, when the piece of html is being included.

But, this doesn't work of course. The base html is rendered first, so the element will be added to the javascriptList array after it has been rendered. My approach must be wrong.

In my project this reusable code is actually a form with some extra buttons that insert content to the textarea's (so a tinyMCE, but much much much more simplistic). I would like to reuse this code on several pages (create, update).

Any thoughts are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend you to add a javascript block in your `base.html.twig` :

You can add a block in your `base.html.twig` after your script load :

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% for js in javascriptList %}
        <script src="{{ asset(js) }}"></script>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

<script type="text/javascript">
{% block afterJavascriptLoad %}

{% endblock %}
</script>
```

With inheritance you'll be able to execute javascript after all script load in nested template :

```
{% extends base.html.twig %}

{% block afterJavascriptLoad %}
    //Your code to be executed after base.html script load
{% endblock %}
```

Having html code and javascript code is not a very good practice. For exemple if you have 3 tinyMCE redactor in your page, you'll load 3 times tinyMCE.

For me the best way is to have your template like this :

**base.html.twig**:

```
{% block container %}
content goes here
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {% for js in javascriptList %}
        <script src="{{ asset(js) }}"></script>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block afterJavascriptLoad %}
    //Your code to be executed after base.html script load
{% endblock %}
```

**pageWithTinyMCE.html.twig** :

```
{% extends base.html.twig %}

{% block container %}
    <h1>Demo</h1>

    Bla bla

    Code I want to reuse:

    {% include 'code-without-js.html.twig' %}
    {% set javascriptList = javascriptList|merge(['js/tooltip.js']) %}
{% endblock %}

{% block afterJavascriptLoad %}
     //Custom javascript for the page
{% endblock %}
```